# Thymeleaf: css path not found and applied

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Somehow i got trouble figuring out the correct path. See below for the hierarchy:

[image: project hierarchy]

Found out that the browser sends a request to `http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`, which does not work. Are the packages located correctly?

It also works fine if the `index.html` is located in the assets folder as well.

git repo: https://github.com/elps/elpsstackoverflowrepo

Comment: What do you want to do there with thymeleaf? Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

try these:

```
<link href="../static/assets/vendor/font-awsome/css/font-awsome.min.css" th:href="@{/assets/vendor/font-awsome/css/font-awsome.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../static/assets/vendor/font-awsome/css/font-awsome.min.css" th:href="@{/assets/vendor/simple-line-icon/css/simple-line-icon.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: it would be great if you could commit your code on git for more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to deploy to a server.

> For example, if you deploy a myapp.war file into a Tomcat server, your
>   application will probably be accessible as
>   http://localhost:8080/myapp, and myapp will be the context name.

Context-relative URLs start with **/**:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/list}">
```

If your app is installed at http://localhost:8080/myapp, this URL will output:

```
<a href="/myapp/order/list">
```

Therefore, you are missing **static folder** in your url. Pay attention to the deployment process of your application.